# What is the correct way to retrieve data from database using nodejs and MySQL?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've written a code that should retrieve data from database with nodejs and mysql but it's not working.

It says the I didn't installed the mysql module but I did, using npm install:
[image]

The proof that I installed the mysql module successfully:
[image]

Is my code ok ? Keep in mind that I'm completely new to node.js.

```js
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response){
 response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
 response.write('My first node server...');
  var mysql = require('mysql');
   var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host :  'localhost:8888',
    user : 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'test'
   });

   connection.connect();

   connection.query('SELECT * FROM tabel_test', function(err, rows, fields){
     if (!err) {
      console.log('The result is ', rows);
     } else {
      console.log('No results.');
     }
   });

  connection.end();
 response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

Comment: What exactly does "it's not working" mean?

Comment: Can't establish a connection to the server when I use mysql. I use the command terminal with 'node database_nodejs.js' command which is the name of the file where I have the code from my question.

Comment: Do you can show the output console error?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Using express? The mysql module it must be in `node_modules/mysql` if yes.

Comment: Do you have the `node_modules` folder?

Comment: Updated again my question. Added the screenshot with the install of mysql module too.

Comment: Personally I found Sequelize to be more useful than the plain mysql library.

Comment: @Simba, that doesn't help me in my case, but for pure curiosity...Why would that be more useful?

Comment: Just curious, where are you trying to install the module? At project root directory?

Comment: @diegoaguilar, NO, I think it's clear from the paths of my screenshot that I installed the mysql module in the node_modules directory.

Comment: Where did you run npm install from?

Comment: @diegoaguilar, from the cmd terminal when I was in the node-mysql-master directory.

Comment: I know it doesn't help; that's why I wrote it as a comment not an answer. As for more useful ... well, it's an ORM, so you get to use models and such; it abstracts your code away from the DB itself. It also supports multiple databases, which is helpful if you ever wanted to switch to postrgreSQL, for example.

Comment: @Simba +1, when looking for an ORM consider Bookshelf.js as well ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code seems fine, the exception says that you do not have the `mysql` module, that could be technically true.

Make sure you have the `node_modules\mysql` folder in the *current working directory*, or that you have installed it globally with `npm install -g mysql`.

By the way I suggested the `package.json` file, because in there you could define the required version of the `mysql` module. Then if you do `npm intall` in the folder, the enumerated dependencies will be downloaded to the current working directory. This also make it easier for others to use you code, if you put it into a git repository.

Comment: Updated my question. Added the screenshot with the install of mysql module too.

Comment: Well, it may be built there, but that does not mean, that is available for your app. Use the global install command, and show us the output. If you have a `package.json`, that would be great too.

Comment: What does this mean: "If you have a package.json, that would be great too." How will this help me? What should I do?

Comment: @lonut Does `npm ls` run in your project's root shows the mysql package? If not then in the end you need to install it like @meskobalazs said. I personally prefer not to install packages globally, but I am no expert.

Comment: I get a 404 error when I try to install it globally and it says 'node-mysql-master' is not in the npm registry or something like that.

Comment: Yes, because the module is named `mysql`, not `node-mysql-master`. It seems to my you are using a git version for some reason, why?

Comment: From where should I use it then? Indeed is a git version.

Comment: The modules can be downloaded from https://www.npmjs.com/. If you do `npm install mysql` it gets the module from this repository.

Answer (score 0):

if you found the given path  **node/node_modules/mysql/lib**
change the below line 
connection.query('SELECT * FROM test_user', function(err, rows, fields)
connection.end();